# Can I prove some thing about dihedral group in term of it subgroup of permutation group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I just found a book that show dihedral group and interpret as permutation group but the the operation no composition of function as ,but flip,rotation
I wonder if I prove by consider of it is subgroup of permutation group ,Can I do it ? I'm not sure because even the operation of both group define on function be different term.

Comment: Depends on whether you interpret it geometrically or combinatorially. Geometrically, you are invoking the notions of the geometric flips and rotations, which are transformations in Euclidean space. But if you are interested in finite dihedral groups, say acting on $n$ elements, then you can indeed express each flip or rotation as some permutation of those $n$ elements, and can analyze the group as a subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: I consider as geometrically,thank for answer ^ ^

Comment: Then consider them as permutations on the points on the unit circle in the Euclidean plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I am understanding your question correctly, but because you mention "flip", I will assume that you are interested in the isomorphism between $D_3$ and $S_3$. Here's a sketch that might help.

Consider an equilateral triangle with vertices (listed in counter-clockwise order) $A, B, C$. For reasons that will become clear, I'll describe the triangle in its initial position as (A B C). Let $r$ be the rotation counterclockwise by 120 degrees that, for example, carries (A B C) to (C A B). Let $f$ be the flip that carries (A B C) to (A C B). Then, geometrically, $D_3$ is generated by the rotation $r$ and the flip $f$ with the obvious relations. We can also map $r, f$ into $S_3$ by viewing the $r$ as the permutation that carries (1 2 3) to (3 1 2), and $f$ as the permutation that carries (1 2 3) to (1 3 2), then verifying that composition and the appropriate relations are respected.

Comment: Thank for answer ^ ^